# AdSense ads not inserted inside empty zones in website

Tags: adsense

I would like to know if there is a way to somehow declare some ads zones for AdSense. Right now, I am using page level ads, but there are too many ads inserted, and the ones that are inserted in the page are placed randomly and are ruining my design.

I tried to set a min-height and a min-width to divs that I want the ads placed in, but that didn't do anything.

Is there anyway to tell Google where they should insert the ads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not... that is the whole point of Auto Ads (page-level ads) ... google decides where to put them, and locations usually suck ... so it looks bad, and you [make less $$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Is3JRQNyHJI)

You should really place your ads yourself. Is your site on WordPress?

Comment: Thanks for your response, yeah after some time i  created my own  ad units and placed them myself. No my site is not using wp, its a laravel news site, so i just placed the ad code inside my templates .